# How to delete record from WebSql Database as well as Server Database

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, web-sql

I created a small application using websql database using google chrome and use sync procedure. When I insert any data that data store into the local database as well as server database but when I delete local database local database successfully deleted but server database remain same.

I want to delete same record in both side same time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think you may need to do some further research on the subject before you can get helpful answers here. PHP is a server-side language, whereas Web SQL is a client-side technology. The two have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Schalus i am working on the sync process so data is inserted into client side as well as server side but deletion process is only working on the local database not the server side.

Comment: Something is missing in your question, you know it for sure but not phrasing the question correctly for someone who has no idea what exactly it means by your "sync process". It can be an AJAX call or some thing else( if it is a native app), so what is your sync process?

Answer (score 0):

Update the local record Auto increment value into 0, get this records in server side while sync and execute the delete query server side.
you can't delete directly in both client and server side..